# Ember + Mirage and relationships

Tags: ember.js

i'm working with Ember 2.6 and currently using Mirage for a client hosted static database.

I started using fixtures du provide the sample data, but I cannot make the relationships work.

I have 2 entities : island and spot, with a Many to One relationship

```
//mirage/models/spot.js
import { Model, belongsTo } from 'ember-cli-mirage';   
export default Model.extend({
  island: belongsTo()
});
```

and

```
//mirage/models/island.js
import { Model, hasMany } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default Model.extend({
  spots: hasMany()
});
```

and my fixture data

```
//mirage/fixture/spots.js
export default [
  {id: '1', name: 'test spot', island_id: [1]},
}
```

and

```
//mirage/fixture/islands.js
export default [
  {id: '1', name: 'Island 1 Name', permit: null, spot_ids: [1]},
}
```

my config.js is just a simple getAll

```
  this.get('/islands', function(schema, request){
    return schema.islands.all();
  });
```

But when I call it, I got my islands, but the relationships are missing.

Using the default json api adapter.

How to make Mirage return json data with the given relationships ?
I tried to set the relation in both sides and 2 at the same time and neither provides the child entity.

Here is a link of my project on github : 
https://github.com/drallieiv/StreetpassTips/tree/feature/showRealDataForIslands/mirage

Answer (score 0):

Try it with no underscores between the relationship properties in the fixture files.

For example:

```
//mirage/fixture/spots.js
export default [
  {id: '1', name: 'test spot', islandId: 1},
}
```

Also in the models you have to give hasMany and belongsTo a model
Like `hasMany('spot')` and `belongsTo('island')`

Comment: I have looked at the JSON API specs (http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) 


Shouldn't the GET to islands should return included elements ?


With what I got I receive this parsed json (chrome debugger)


![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/1yhAgqv.jpg)

Comment: What the call to islands returns looks normal, but I expected either the spots to be embedded in the result, or my ember app calling
GET /spots/:id for each linked result.

Comment: Edited to remove array brackets around `islandId` value in the answer. That would matter.

Comment: @AdrienNGUYEN In your question, can you include the part of your application that is calling your API? Does it request for the `spots` records to be included via the URL `include` parameter? http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes

Comment: I can't, it is ember data which is doing the call. I have no idea how to tell it to do that or not.

I got a few answers on ember slack and I am thinking about giving up pretender and ember-data and use pojos from an ES6 module.